# what is easiest way to print the 50th word in python

Tags: python, full-text-search

okay so, I have created a list contains 100 words, what is easiest way to print the 50th word in python with out knowing the number of words in the list. so let's say that that I have 1098 words in a list, how do I find the middle word.

```
groceries=["rice","curd","milk","wheat","kjhdlu","rewqtq","erhaehwjrtj","weghfoiuqg","kgfu"]
middle_index=len(groceries)//2
middle_word= groceries[middle_index]
print(middle_word)
```

I did this I got the right answer but is there a easier way to do it

Comment: Your method is easy enough.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be the "middle" when the list has an even number of elements. e.g., [1,2,3,4] which is the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what you mean by "easiest".
You can actually just do it in one line, and I think it is already far more than easy:

```
groceries[len(groceries)//2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest and most efficient method.

```
print(groceries[len(groceries)//2])
```

And if your list contains only numeric elements, then you can use the median function of the statistics module to do that.
Eg:

```
import statistics as st
mid = st.median(your_list_of_integers)
print(mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP says   "*a list contains 100 words, what is easiest way to print the 50th word*"

**50th word will be index 49**

```
groceries=["rice","curd","milk","wheat","kjhdlu","rewqtq","erhaehwjrtj","weghfoiuqg","kgfu"]

    if len(groceries)%2==1:
        middle_index=len(groceries)//2  # for odd values
    else:
        middle_index=len(groceries)//2 -1  # for even values
```

Comment: The question has two parts. The 50th element in a 100 element list is _list[49]. That is unambiguous. However, the question then goes on to ask how to find the "middle" element in a list of length 1098. As that's an even number there is no "middle"

Comment: as 100 is an even number; for 1098 index will be list[548]

Comment: No need for the test, you can use `groceries[len(groceries)//2-1+len(groceries)%2]`